# Find the list of all persisted dataframes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a long spark code similar to below which has a lot of keywords :

```
df = spark.sql("""
select * from abc
""")

df.persist()

df2 = spark.sql("""
select * from def
""")

df2.persist()

df3 = spark.sql("""
select * from mno""")
```

I want to find out all the dataframes which have been persisted and store them in a list.

Output:

```
l1 = [df, df2]
```

How can we proceed with this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

df = spark.sql("""
select * from abc
""")

df.persist()

df2 = spark.sql("""
select * from def
""")

df2.persist()

df3 = spark.sql("""
select * from mno
""")

dfNameList = []

for k, v in globals().items():
    if isinstance(v, DataFrame):
        # k is the name of DF, v is DF itself.
        if v.storageLevel.useMemory == True:
            dfNameList.append(k)

print(dfNameList)
```

Output:

```
['df', 'df2']
```

- Loop `globals().items()`;
- Find `DataFrame` instance;
- Determine whether DF is persistent in memory;
- Collect the DF name and print.

If you want to put all DF in the list instead of DF names, just append the `v` to list.

Output will like:

```
[DataFrame[fieldOne: typeOne, fieldTwo: typeTwo, ……], DataFrame[fieldOne: typeOne, fieldTwo: typeTwo，……]]
```